# Convert any word of U.S. language into U.K. language

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I was trying to replace the specific word from US English to UK English in power point using VBA coding but the codes not working and i am not getting any other way to do this. Please anyone help if possible..
Below are the lines for VBA code for the same---

```
Sub test()


For i = 1 To 100
Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(i)
For Each shp In sld.Shapes
   
    If shp.TextFrame.TextRange.LanguageID = msoLanguageIDEnglishUS Then
       shp.TextFrame.TextRange.LanguageID = msoLanguageIDEnglishUK
    End If
    
Next shp
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What did this have to do with Python? I removed the tag.

Comment: Your code, as it stands, runs 100 times on slide 1 ... is that what you mean, or should `Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)` be `Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(i)` (ie replacing **1** with **i**? This assumes you do have 100 slides in the presentation?!

Comment: And your code, as it stands, changes the entire shape's textrange, if set to US English, to UK English. There's nothing there that narrows it down to a single word or range of words.  Also, note that not all shapes have TextFrames, so you'll want to surround everything here with If shp.HasTextFrame Then ... If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then

Comment: Not sure if this applies to your situation or not, but I believe objects contained in groups will also be missed by your code. If objects are grouped in your presentation, you can assess if shp.Type = 6, and if it is true then you'd need to search the shp.GroupItems for the desired text to replace.

Comment: `=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1) & "u" & RIGHT(A1,1)`  :)  Just kidding.

Answer (score 0):

A few mods to what you already have has it working here, within limitations; it will only find text in shapes/placeholders, not charts, smartart, inserted graphics and such, and as pointed out already, it won't find text in groups of shapes.

```
Option Explicit
' Add this to every module

Sub test()
' It's good practice always to DIM all variables:
Dim i As Long
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape

' Use ActivePresentation.Slides.Count rather than
' a hard-coded number; works with any presentation that way
For i = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count

Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(i)
For Each shp In sld.Shapes
    If shp.HasTextFrame Then
        If shp.TextFrame.TextRange.LanguageID = msoLanguageIDEnglishUS Then
           shp.TextFrame.TextRange.LanguageID = msoLanguageIDEnglishUK
        End If
    End If  ' HasTextFrame
Next shp
Next i

End Sub
```